# Add Each Array Object to HashTable

Tags: windows, powershell, hashtable

I have a PowerShell script, which contain an `$arrayip` and `$hash`. I want to add each IP address from `$arrayip` to be a name or key in my `$hash` hashtable.

**My wrong syntax:**

```
$arrayip = @("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3")
$hash = @{
    name = "Name"
    $arrayip = "Is a server IP"
}
```

**Bad Result for me:**

```
PS C:\> $hash

Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
name                           Name                                            
{192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, ... Is a server IP
```

[image: image result]

Comment: What is your desired result? Do you want the addresses to be keys or values in your hashtable? That's a fundamental difference. What do you want to do with the hash once it holds the addresses?

Comment: yes sir, i want to add each ip as a key, and the values are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create array of hashes, however, you still need to think what to put in "name" property in hash.

```
# declare array of ip hashes
$iphashes = @();
# for each array ip
for($i = 0; $i -lt $arrayip.Count; $i++){
    $hash = @{
        name = "Name";
        ip = $arrayip[$i];
    }
    # add hash to array of ip hashes
    $iphashes += $hash;
}
```

Comment: When I type $hash in console, return one value for 'ip', I want to add each IPs for each values, for example: 
ip-----192.168.1.1
ip-----192.168.1.2
ip-----192.168.1.3
name-----name

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
$arrayips = @("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3")

$foreachhash = foreach($arrayip in $arrayips)
{
    $hash = [ordered]@{'Name'=$arrayip;
                       'Is a server IP' = $arrayip
                      } #end $hash

    write-output (New-Object -Typename PSObject -Property $hash)
} #end foreach

$foreachhash
```

Produces:

[image]

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: The $hash keys in console contain one value!, i want to add each key for each IPs, for example:
ip-----192.168.1.1 ip-----192.168.1.2 ip-----192.168.1.3 name-----name

Comment: I have updated my answer to add IP under the Name column. I also added [ordered] so that the Name column will always be first.

Comment: you use this trick: write-output (New-Object -Typename PSObject -Property $hash)...
please can you write $hash in your console ?  
then what did you see? tow values, (name and is server ip) 
now i want to add each ips to be a key or Name of $hash 
i don't want New-Object sir

Comment: Oh, a key value pair? From this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx The Key needs to be unique. $arrayips = [ordered]@{"IP1" = "192.168.1.1"; "IP2" = "192.168.1.2"; "IP3" = "192.168.1.3"} If you then check $arrayips it will look the way I think you are asking.

Comment: The other option is to set a variable for your whole foreach loop. Then display that. Formatting might be a bit odd as a comment.
$foreachhashes = foreach($arrayip in $arrayips)
{
    $hash = [ordered]@{'Name'='IP';
                       'Is a server IP' = $arrayip
              
             } #end $hash

    write-output (New-Object -Typename PSObject -Property $hash)
}
$foreachhashes

Comment: yes sir, I know the key must unique, but i want to add each ip as key and each vale as ip for example $hash {'192.168.1.1' = 192.168.1.1' '192.168.1.2' = '192.168.1.2'}, it's possible to do that form array to my $hash?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155184/discussion-between-tim-haintz-and-schoolfordesign).

Comment: Updated answer after comments.

Comment: Sir, is that $hash table ?

Comment: @SchoolforDesign I’m not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

For adding the array elements as keys to an existing hashtable you could do something like this:

```
$arrayip = '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3'
$hash    = @{ 'Name' = 'Name' }

$arrayip | ForEach-Object {
    $hash[$_] = 'Is a server IP'
}
```